# Android Webview and history.pushState?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

The Android Webview allows an Android application to handle a user clicking on a link by opening the destination within the webview, instead of opening it in an external browser.

It is then possible to maintain a history of these page loads so that a user can go forward and backward within the webview, much like a "real" browser:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#NavigatingHistory

My questions are:

- Can the Android webview history management "natively" handle a webpage pushing to the history stack using something like window.history.pushState?

  - If so, what data structures/API are used to manage the history? How does the webview differentiate between two versions of the page that have the same URL but different DOM states?
  - If not, can such support be implemented by an application developer?
- Which HTML5 APIs (if any) does the Webview support?

Comment: Ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

To handle this api you can override `doUpdateVisitedHistory` method in WebViewClient. For example using Kotlin

```kotlin
val webView = findViewById(R.id.…)
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun doUpdateVisitedHistory(view: WebView?, url: String?, isReload: Boolean) {
        // for example, we want to change icon in toolbar when we can go back
        if (view?.canGoBack() == true)
            toolbar.navigationIcon = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.back)
        } else {
            toolbar.navigationIcon = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.close)
        }
    }
```